# Sci-Fi and Fantasy holidays

Tags: science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre, holidays

Star Wars Day is probably the most famous sci-fi/fantasy holiday. What others are there? Please only include examples that are celebrated by a significant amount of people.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a "list" question.

Comment: @fizzyboots It may be, but it would only be off topic of I asked for a list of works, which I did not.

Comment: "or any other question with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer that anyone may add to.

Please include the holiday's name, its date, a brief description and why it's on that specific date. Include a link to prove the holiday is celebrated by multiple people. Arrange the holidays by date.

- **January 17** - *[Enterprise Day](https://continuingmissionsta.com/2020/01/17/happy-enterprise-day/)* - For people outside the U.S. who write their calendar dates with the day first and month second, 17/01 is known as "Enterprise Day" because that's the serial number of the Starship Enterprise: NCC-1701. Fans often build models of the Enterprise to celebrate the day.
- **March 25** - *[Tolkien Reading Day](https://www.fiatphysica.com/blog/pop-culture/celebrated-geek-science-holidays)* - Celebrates the literary works of J.R.R. Tolkien - The 25th of March is the date of the downfall of the Lord of the Rings (Sauron) and the fall of Barad-dûr.
- **April 5** - *[First Contact Day](http://www.startrek.com/article/happy-first-contact-day)* - Celebrates *Star Trek* - The creation of the first warp drive starship by Dr. Zefram Cochrane, and the subsequent contact with the Vulcans, happens on this day in 2063.
- **April 26** - *[Alien Day](http://www.comingsoon.net/extras/news/671335-alien-day-reebok-stompers)* - Celebrates the *Alien* franchise - The titular aliens originated on a planet known as LV-426, so 4/26 was chosen.
- **April 28** - *[National Superhero Day](http://comicbook.com/2016/04/28/happy-national-superhero-day-/)* - Celebrates superheroes - In 1995, Marvel employees chose this day for an unknown reason.
- **May 2** - *[National Harry Potter Day](http://whatnationaldayisit.com/day/Harry-Potter/)* - Celebrates *Harry Potter* - The Battle of Hogwarts occurred on this day.
- **May 4** - *[May the Fourth Be With You/Star Wars Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Day)* - Celebrates *Star Wars* - Falls on May 4th due to the date sounding like the phrase "May the Force be with you."
- **The first Saturday of May** - *[Free Comic Book Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Comic_Book_Day)* - Celebrates the comic book industry -  Originally held May 4, 2002, one day after the opening of *Spider-Man*, in order to capitalize on its promotion.
- **May 25** - *[Towel Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towel_Day)* - Celebrates *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* - First held two weeks after the death of author Douglas Adams, celebrated by carrying a towel due to its importance in the series
- **June 16** - *[Captain Picard Day](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Picard_Day)* -
  Celebrates Captain Jean-Luc Picard as the loved and fearless leader of the Starship Enterprise (stardate 47457.1).
- **August 29** - *[Judgement Day](https://www.fiatphysica.com/blog/pop-culture/celebrated-geek-science-holidays)* - Celebrates *Terminator* - In the *Terminator* franchise, Skynet became self-aware and declared war on humanity on this day.
- **September 1** - [*Hogwarts Day*](https://time.com/4476143/hogwarts-day-pictures-train/) - the day all Hogwarts students return to school using the King's Cross platform 9 3/4. Many fans take a pilgrimage once a year to the real King's Cross on this day.
- **September 8** - [*Star Trek Day*](https://nypost.com/2020/09/03/star-trek-marks-anniversary-with-24-hour-virtual-celebration/) - marks the anniversary of the very first star trek episode ever aired on television which was September 8th, 1966.
- **September 21** - [*Sid Meier's Civilization V Day*](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/29661/Maryland_Declares_September_21_Civilization_V_Day.php) - An officially recognized local holiday that celebrates the accomplishments of Sid Meier, a game designer connected to several science fiction video games and video games with science fiction elements - September 21 was the original release date of *Sid Meier's Civilization V*.
- **September 22** - [*Hobbit Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobbit_Day) - Celebrates Tolkien's Middle-earth works - Birthday of Bilbo and Frodo Baggins.
- **September 25** - [*National Comic Book Day*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhr6UeVQPWk) - Celebrates comic books - Date chosen for unknown reasons.
- **September 26** - *[Batman Day](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/09/26/its-batman-day)* - Celebrates the Batman comics - A day designated by DC Comics as the day for an annual celebration of the Dark Knight, although Kotaku argues it should be celebrated [on **June 26th**](http://kotaku.com/batman-day-is-happening-on-the-wrong-day-1733058818), since that is when his parents died
- **October 21** - *[Marty McFly Day](https://www.fiatphysica.com/blog/pop-culture/celebrated-geek-science-holidays)* - Celebrates *Back to the Future*  - McFly and Doc Brown arrived in the future on this date.

Comment: “In the Terminator franchise, Skynet became self-aware and declared war on humanity on this day” — hooray!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite My Roomba did seem a little excited last August...

Comment: Just barely beaten for Towel Day... I was adding it at the same time!

Comment: Not sure if [Ratcatcher's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratcatcher%27s_Day) would count, since it's not clear to me if the Pied Piper of Hamelin is fantasy.

Comment: @Thunderforge, Pied Piper would be mythology stackexchange.